# For loop incredibly slow in Android Studio debugger, fast without it

Tags: android, performance, loops

I am initializing an array of 30 MB in Android Studio.

```
byte[] myarray = new byte[30 * 1024 * 1024];
for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    myarray[i] = 0;
}
```

Around this I had a time measurement with SystemClock that calculates how many milliseconds the loop takes.

It's 2.5 minutes if the app runs started with Android Studio. No breakpoints involved of course.
It's 0.5 seconds if the app runs started directly without Android Studio.

When I call other operations on this array such as System.arraycopy I don't see such a huge difference. I understand there is a difference between debugging or not but this is a factor of 300.

What is happening here and how can I modify this so I can debug my app efficiently?

Comment: I can only assume is that the debugger is preparing to be able to show you the values of 30MB that makes such a huge difference. To debug efficiently, I think best course of action would be to reduce the array size to as less as possible to still be relevant for your test case

Comment: Unfortunately I have to leave that working for every case, because I need to debug other parts of the code too. Having a debug mode with very limited possibilities is not feasible.

Comment: But do you really need to initiate a 30MB array to debug things? For example, if a view is not appearing properly, the array is irrelevant, no need to have it 30MB size in case of ui debugging and stuff like that.

Comment: Not for UI debugging but to have real life data run through my algorithm and evaluate data. And I don't see why running this loop would require lots of background activity. I am not in stepping mode but I run over this loop without stopping. So there is no need to prepare displaying data. I prefer switching this off if possible, better than having a debug version that can't show what the real app would do.

Comment: since it involves the heap the heap monitor/memory allocation tracker could add work - but I recall having to start those - one thing about the profiler is it continues to run a session after stopping app and restarting app - having to stop it manually.

Comment: Well, consider that debugging mode was made in order for you to find bugs in your program. The tool is made to answer as many test cases as possible. Having a 30MB array isn't your every day test case so obviously the debugger won't perform optimally for that operation. Maybe you can try a different approach, using attach debugger feature. You run the APK normally and after the array has been initialized, you click on "attach debugger" and from this point on the debugger will be available, skipping the loading part of the array.

Comment: The situation that I have to examine involves that large input. The tip to attach later can reduce waiting time but I really can't imagine this is the only solution. A debugger that can't decide to not interfere code without a breakpoint is not a debugger to me.

Comment: How do you want a debugger to know when to not do the only action it is meant to do? You use a debugger to view code. How do you want the debugger to know you only want to debug specific part of the code? Let's say you have a class with a 30MB data member. You might want to examine that data member from any given function of the class. How can the debugger know you won't do that and so to skip this load? I don't see how you want such a debugger to even be implemented.

Comment: **"How do you want a debugger to know when to not do the only action it is meant to do?"** If I have no breakpoint set then nothing must be displayed at this code and there is no reason to prepare anything to display. Imagine a debugger that prepares to display everything that happens, it wouldn't get the app even started in an acceptable time. I have used debuggers in other languages before and had applications with large data processing running in them. There never was a problem.

Comment: Hi @Droidum, have you found what causes such slowness? We have three nested for-loops in our program, and it works pathetically slow when debugger is attached.

Comment: @MikalaiDaronin no unfortunately I haven't found more about this.